# Display view result in a div in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this :

```
     <div>@Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "Index", "Home")</div>

     <div id="ToDisplayResult></div>
```

Is it possible to display the View or PartialView returned by the controller in a specific div ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>@Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "mylink" })</div>
<div id="ToDisplayResult></div>
```

and in a separate javascript file AJAXify:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#ToDisplayResult').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And for completeness of my answer (not that this is something I would recommend) you could use the Ajax helpers:

```
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "MyLink", 
        "Index", 
        "Home", 
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ToDisplayResult" }
    )
</div>
<div id="ToDisplayResult></div>
```

Just make sure you have included the proper unobtrusive script to your page in this case:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add this:

```
<div id="ToDisplayResult>@Html.Action("MyActionThatReturnsPartial", "Home")</div>
```

It will display the partial view result where you desire.  Make sure that your controller returns a partial view result, of course.

Comment: I have several ActonLink (menu), depending of the item in the menu I have to display in a different div

Comment: Why not just use JQuery's ajax to load your partial results and put into the appropriate div?  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.

Answer (score 0):

the most basic way of updating a div would be using jQuery .load

```
$('#ToDisplayResult').load('/SomeController/Action');
```

see this question for more details:
[How can I reload a div with a PartialView in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433419/how-can-i-reload-a-div-with-a-partialview-in-asp-net-mvc-using-jquery)